# Error in FeatureUnion Sklearn Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID Text 
1  qwerty
2  asdfgh
```

I am trying to create `md5` hash for **Text** field and remove `ID` field from the dataframe above. To achieve that i have created a simple `pipeline` with custom transformers from `sklearn`.

Here is the code I have used:

```
class cust_txt_col(sklearn.base.BaseEstimator, sklearn.base.TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self

    def hash_generate(self, txt):

        m = hashlib.md5()
        text = str(txt)
        long_text = ' '.join(text.split())
        m.update(long_text.encode('utf-8'))
        text_hash= m.hexdigest()
        return text_hash

    def transform(self, x):
        return x[self.key].apply(lambda  z: self.hash_generate(z)).values

class cust_regression_vals(sklearn.base.BaseEstimator, sklearn.base.TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, x):
        x = x.drop(['Gene', 'Variation','ID','Text'], axis=1)
        return x.values

fp = pipeline.Pipeline([

 ('union', pipeline.FeatureUnion([
        ('hash', cust_txt_col('Text')), # can pass in either a pipeline
        ('normalized', cust_regression_vals()) # or a transformer
    ]))
])
```

When I run this I receive the follwoing error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Can you, please, tell me what is wrong with my code?

if i run the classes one by one :

for **cust_txt_col** i got below o/p

```
['3e909f222a1e06098ec7ca1ea7e84540' '1691bdba3b75df145169e0501369fce3'
 '1691bdba3b75df145169e0501369fce3' ..., 'e11ec9863aaeb93f77a231319021e14d'
 '851c517b2af0a46cb9bc9373b748b6ff' '0ffe46fc75d21a5347b1f1a5a84526ad']
```

for **cust_regression_vals** i got below o/p

```
[[qwerty],
  [asdfgh]]
```

Comment: Should not it be `cust_txt_col(dataframe['Text'])`? Also, what output do you receive if you run classes one by one?

Comment: @E.Z. updeted my post with classes o/p

Comment: The problem might be in the shape of `cust_regression_vals`; try to add in the end of the second class `return x.ravel().values` and verify if that is ok. If not, could you post the output of `cust_txt_col.shape`?

Comment: @E.Z...  cust_txt_col.shape is (3321,) and cust_regression_vals.shape is (3321, 8)

Answer (score 3):

`cust_txt_col` is returning a 1d array. `FeatureUnion` demands that each constituent transformer returns a 2d array.

Comment: Also suggest how the OP @Backtrack can solve the problem. Like changing the output shape of transform() using reshape(). Then this answer will be complete.